# Adobe Phonegap Google Play Application + Android 5.0

Tags: android, cordova

I have problem with Adobe Google Play Application - i use that great tool
"phonegap serve". And when i develop my application on android 4.* everything works fine - but when i run it on android 5.0 just after upload
my phonegap app to Phonegap Google Play Application i get just white screen.

This is what i see in android sdk debuger:

```
08-27 10:33:02.366: I/chromium(9770): [INFO:CONSOLE(247)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined", source: file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html (247)

08-27 10:33:02.406: I/chromium(9770): [INFO:CONSOLE(140)] "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){var define,module,exports;
```

I don't use any 'socket.io' in my application - as i guess this is thing added by adobe phonegap app to maintain things like app refresh. So i try
"phonegap serve --no-autoreload" but this not helps.

Oh, and one more important, the last thing - when i build application to apk - everythings work ok on android 5.

Comment: file an issue on https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. But I am not sure if I did not do anything wrong. It is for me a new technology ...

Comment: if it works on android 4 and you do the same on android 5, it should be a problem in the app

Comment: That's what I think. But I tried it on three different phones - and perhaps there is some other factors than just the version of the system. Which maybe I should check out - but I have no idea what they were. 

But now I made a issue on github. So maybe someone helps me ;)